# Checking if my bot has permissions to create channels. in V14

Tags: discord, discord.js

Im trying to make sure my bot has permissions to make channels before running the command to avoid and errors, here's the code i have:

```
if (!interaction.guild.me.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
  interaction.reply("I Dont have perms to create channels");;
}
```

yet i still get this error:

```
        if (!interaction.guild.me.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'permissions')
```

did they change something in the new v14? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to access the [`GuildMemberManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/14.0.3/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=me) before the `me` object, but you also should use the [`PermissionsBitField`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/14.0.3/class/PermissionsBitField) object to reference a permission:

```
if (!interaction.guild.members.me.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.Administrator)) {
    interaction.reply("I don't have permissions to create channels");
}
```